# React Table, accessor function does not work properly with momentjs

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-table

I am using react table, formatting a datetime in a cell like so:

Within columns list:

```
  {
    Header: "Logged At",
    id: "loggedAt",
    accessor: d =>
      moment(d.expense_incur_datetime).format("HH:mm - ddd d/M/YYYY")
  },
```

For some reason, the output of the accessor function is always the same, and is wrong. The values of the input datetimes are correct, but momentjs always returns the same data, regardless of the value of the incur_datetime value.

I've used functions in the accessor before, which have worked, so I'm confident that this is possible, but in this case it is not working.

Comment: Does `moment(d.expense_incur_datetime).isValid()` returns `true`?

Comment: @ChristiaanScheermeijer It returns true

Comment: this should work man nothing is wrong here , just make sure expense_incur_datetime is valid and inside passed data

Comment: How did you solve this? I am facing exact issue. I was able to make it work like this `accessor: d => \`moment(d.expense_incur_datetime).format("HH:mm - ddd d/M/YYYY")\`` wondering if that's the correct way to do it or just a workaround